# How to see the contact number in Android while sharing text and dealing with multiple apps?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

We are developing an app which shares certain text with other contacts via SMS/Whatsapp/Viber etc. (i.e. the apps which binds with a phone number). The issue is that, how to get the contact number with whom we are sharing the text? Importing the contacts to the app, may allow SMS only and whatsapp icon may not appear.

Is there any way to get (or intercept) the phone number for selected contact and also multiple sharing options?
(Note: It works fine on iPhone.)